# Difference between $@ and $! in perl

Tags: perl

What is the difference between `$@` and `$!` in Perl? Errors associated with `eval` are outputted using `$@` . `$!` is also used for capturing the error. Then what is the difference between both of them?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> The variables `$@` , `$!` , `$^E` , and `$?` contain information about different types of error conditions that may appear during execution of a Perl program. The variables are shown ordered by the "distance" between the subsystem which reported the error and the Perl process. They correspond to errors detected by the Perl interpreter, C library, operating system, or an external program, respectively.

Answer (score 11):

`$!` is set when a system call fails.

```
open my $fh, '<', '/foobarbaz' or die $!
```

This will die outputting "No such file or directory".

`$@` contains the argument that was passed to `die`. Therefore:

```
eval {
    open my $fh, '<', '/foobarbaz' or die $!
};
if ( $@ ) {
   warn "Caught exception: $@";
}
```

It make no sense to check `$@` without using some form of `eval` and it makes no sense to check `$!` when you haven't called a function that can set it in the case of an error.

Answer (score 1):

based on [perl_doc](https://www.perl.com/pub/2004/06/18/variables.html/)

```
$!; show C library\'s errno
$@; show compile error
```